# Updating value of class variables - C++

Tags: c++, variables, updating

I'm just beginning to learn how to code and I've come across a problem I can't seem to solve.
More specifically the problem occurs in the "borrows" function.

In the following program I am somehow unable to update the value of the public class variable "stock" even though I used getters and setters.
It seems to be updated correctly on the cout right after but not "saved permanently". My guess is that it's modifying a copy of the variable rather than the variable itself.

I have attached my code to the post! Please let me know if I should upload the whole file!

Thanks in advance!

```
void Book::borrows() {
    int searchid;
    bool isfound=false;
    cout<<"Please enter the unique ID of the book:\t\t";
    cin>>searchid;
    for(auto i:myBooks){
        if (i.id==searchid){
            cout<<"This book matches your search:\t"; print(i);
            if (i.stock==0) {
                cout<<"Book is out of stock!"<<endl;
            } else {
                setStock((i.stock-1));
                cout<<"Successfully borrowed!! Now there are only "<<getStock()<<" copies left in stock!"<<endl;
            }
            isfound=true;
        }
    }
    if (isfound== false){
        cout<<"++++\t\tBook not found++++\t\t"<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}

int Book::getStock() const {
    return stock;
}

void Book::setStock(int newstock) {
    Book::stock = newstock;
}
```

Edit 1:

Here is my Class structure and my vector:

```
class Book{
public:
    int id;
    string title;
    int stock;

    void add();
    void displayall();
    void displayspecific();
    void print(Book);
    void borrows();
    void returns();

    int getStock() const;

    void setStock(int stock);
};

vector<Book> myBooks;
```

Comment: Looks like you need to separate the concept of a *single* book versus a *container* of books.  For example, you could use `std::vector<Book>` as a library.  You would search the library for a specific book.

Comment: Including the `class` definition of `Book` would be helpful.

Comment: The posted code doesn't try to update `id`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Hi! Thanks for the quick reply! I actually am using a vector to keep track of the books! Gonna update the question right away!

Comment: I deleted my answer because it didn't really address the problem. However, it may have been close. Your `borrows` function appears to change the `stock` of the object on which it is called, rather than on one of the books in the `myBooks` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem is that you are operating on a copy of the Book object, not the setters and getters of the members of a book.

```
for(auto i:myBooks){
```

You need

```
for(auto &i:myBooks){
```

But as other have pointed out, you need 2 classes, Library and Book.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thomas Matthews' comment. Your current `Book` structure does not make sense because most of the methods are for doing work with a collection of `Book`s rather than a particular `Book`

If you were to refer to a collection of books as a `Library` then the code below would make more sense for delegating where work is done among `Book` and `Library`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Book {
public:
    int id;
    string title;
    int stock;

    // These methods operate on this particular Book instance
    int getStock() const;
    void setStock(int);
};

int Book::getStock() const {
    return stock;
}

void Book::setStock(int newstock) {
    stock = newstock;
}

class Library {
public:
    vector<Book> myBooks;

    // These methods operate on the vector of books
    void add();
    void displayall();
    void displayspecific();
    //void print(Book); // This method probably belongs inside Book
    void borrows();
    void returns();
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Rewriting `borrows` in terms of a `Library` method would mean operating on that `Library`'s `myBooks` vector. When you find the particular `Book` you want inside the vector then you can call its getters and setters which should work fine

Addressing your question, in your current code this is iterating over your `Book`s and giving you a copy of each one:

```
for(auto i:myBooks)
```

You want this to get a reference instead of a copy:

```
for(auto& i:myBooks)
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! This was very motivating!